# Elasticsearch Shard Location

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to setup an elasticsearch cluster and have a question thats bothering me. I am transitioning from Marklogic to Elasticsearch and have this concept of storing data on a different disk rather than on the same disk where my software i.e. MarkLogic is installed. I know how to do it in MarkLogic but somehow can not find anything on this on elasticsearch. Can anyone point me to a document that can help me configure my shard on a different machine where elasticsearch is not installed?

Thanks,
S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to change the [`path.data` setting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/important-settings.html#path-settings) in your `elasticsearch.yml` configuration file:

```
path:
    data:
        - /mnt/hda1
        - /mnt/hda2
        - /mnt/hda3
```

You can use a single location or several and when you do, ES will store your index data on those locations. Note that data pertaining to a given shard will always be located at the same path location.